# uploading photos

Tags: uploads

I am very new to word press, and I have been trying to upload photos to my posts, and each time I do, it says there is an error  "has failed to upload due to an error
Failed to write file to disk."

I used to be able to do this, and now it will not let me.

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? Sounds like a permissions error or a storage capacity error though.

Answer (score 0):

This might came from your access right:

- First, check that you are a writer or an admin (See User in Admin Panel) > general > Role
- Second, if this is not the problem check the rights of yoursource files into your server ( you can easily check this on your FTP files or if you run it locally directly in the directory)